# Dealloc of UIView subclass prevents running class methods

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode4.2, dealloc

I've created a UIView subclass with a UIButton inside with target on tap inside.
The selector is implemented inside the UIView subclass and linked by Interface Builder.

But when I run addSubview in parent view controller tapping button will cause

> performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated
>   instance

(I use ARC)
I added some console output in dealloc method and I see that right after viewDidLoad ends with addSubview of the UIView subclass, the sublass is deallocated.

How to prevent that sort of situation?
I tried @property(nonatomic, retain), adding instance to some global array...
But no luck.

I understand that ARC releses the object as there is no strong reference left but I couldn't force to prevent that situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a strong reference of your subview class in your View Controller class may help you solve the issue.

```
@property (strong , nonatomic) UIView *subclassName;
```

Comment: How are you creating the reference of UIButton?
Also, are you creating the refernce of ViewController object somewhere? If Yes, than how are you creating it?

Comment: At first I've just created a button in a view and then I created an IBAction touchUpInside (with a few mouse drags)

Now I also created an outlet with @property(nonatomic, strong) but it didn't change the situation.

Comment: ViewController reference is default when creating a new project: @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController; <-- in AppDelegate

Comment: Does your UIView subclass has a nib associated with it? If no , than you dont need an IBOutlet, just creating a property would be fine.
Well can I see your code? may be I will be of some help then.

Comment: Of course it is associated with a nib. I told you that the button and actions has been created via Interface Builder.

Comment: My bad. Missed that point.Sorry.
 It would be helpful if you can share the code.

Comment: Thanks for help, I solved the problem. I made a mistake in nib connections.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing reference of button (UIButton) you are trying to add as subview?

Comment: Button is added with Interface Builder with linked action on Touch Up Inside so I guess the reference is stored and should work. But it's not, so I missing something here

Comment: May be you don't require subclassing UIButton, why not instead use Category

Comment: But I'm not subclassing a UIButton. I'm subclassing a UIView. But all objects inside it with targets can't run as UIView subclass instance is released after addSubview. I've created custom UIViews before with working methods but now I can't repeat that and I can't find the clue which made it working in previous projects

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in linking NIB to Class.

I linked File owner to class instead of linking the UIView object.

Normally when there is working on nib with UIViewController, there is a need to link File Owner to UIViewController class.
But when working on UIView subclass the UIView object must be linked.